How Can I Get Javascript To Run On A Specific Screen Size?
Below is some Javascript that I'm using for the mobile menu on my website. This Javascript stops content outside the menu from scrolling when the mobile menu is open and closes the menu when an item inside of it is clicked.
document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() {
 if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) {
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
 document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }

}


var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var closeHamp = function() {
 document.getElementsByClassName('cp_menuicon')[0].click();
    };



for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
 elements[i].addEventListener('click', closeHamp, false);
    }

Is there a way to set it so that this code only runs when on a specific screen size? I've tried using this Javascript to do so but haven't had any luck getting it to run propperly.
function execute(){
   if(screen.width <= 768) {
   
     }

If anyone has any suggestions as how I could get this Javascript to work on a specific screen size I'd appreciate you letting me know.
My Website

you can use a combination of JS and the window.matchMedia method. This method allows you to add a listener for changes in the screen size and conditionally execute the desired functionality.

I think you are looking for document.body.clientWidth which represent the size of the body tag (borders are not included, but padding is). the screen variable you used represent the real screen width (e.g: 1920) therefore it will not change with the browser resize

the Window object in JavaScript is very powerful. To get the width of your viewport, not counting the URL bar; you would use window.innerWidth.
This returns a number regarding the amount of pixels your current viewport has in width. window.innerHeight does the same, but for height.
Here's the MDN link to window.innerWidth
if you were to interpret rotation from Portrait to Landscape, you can integrate the 'onresize' event like so
// window.addEventListener('onresize', method()); would also work, method being your logic

window.onresize = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {// switch to tablet sizes
        // code for mobile here
    }
}


There is js library https://github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js which allows programmatically responding to media queries.
Simplest usage case:
    var matched = undefined;

    enquire.register("screen and (max-width:768px)", {

        match : function() {
            matched = true;
        },

        unmatch : function() {
            matched = false;
        }
    });
    
    function execute(){
       if(matched) {
            //do stuff
        } else {
            //do other stuff
        }
    }


Introducing an entire library just to manage viewport sizes seems like way too much bloat where window.innerWidth could simply be checked inside of an if/switch statement.

@NikkieDev The problem with your answer is that checking window.innerWidth inside window.onresize  when you open document will never happen - only when you resize window. In that form it is useless. Make that check outside and it will be OK. And my answer - yes, it is overkill - but at least answers originall question.

Certainly not true, as inside the library upon loading the document the 'resize' event is dispatched. Which JS on it's own can do as well with window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))
